# Node.js Socket.IO "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'close'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to close a http server associated with a socket.io instance, using `mySocketIoInstance.close()`, but I am getting the following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'close'
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/test/server/ServerLobbySpec.js:35:20)
  at Socket.Emitter.emit (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
  at Socket.emit (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:128:10)
  at Socket.onconnect (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:306:8)
  at Socket.onpacket (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:206:12)
  at Manager.<anonymous> (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
  at Manager.Emitter.emit (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
  at Manager.ondecoded (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js:270:8)
  at Decoder.<anonymous> (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
  at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/home/jackson/projects/tcg/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/emitter/index.js:132:20)
```

Here's where I'm trying to close it:

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http'),
    expect = require('chai').expect,
    socketIo = require('socket.io'),
    socketIoClient = require('socket.io-client'),
    ServerLobby = require('../../source/server/ServerLobby');

describe('ServerLobby', function () {

    var port = 2468,
        uri = 'http://localhost:' + port;

    describe('is connectable', function () {

        it('should connect', function (done) {

            var httpServer = http.Server().listen(port),
                io = socketIo(httpServer),
                lobby = new ServerLobby(io),
                socket = socketIoClient(uri + lobby.namespace);

            socket.on('connect', function () {

                // HERE
                io.close();
                // HERE

                done();
            });

        });

    });

});
```

I tried commenting-out the `lobby` and `socket` code and just `console.log`'d `io.close` and got `undefined`.

My version is 1.0.6. According to `socket.io/test/socket.io.js` (also 1.0.6), I should be able to close the server in the following way:

```
var http = require('http').Server;
var io = require('..');
var expect = require('expect.js');

// ...

    it('should be able to close sio sending a srv', function() {
        var PORT = 54016;
        var srv = http().listen(PORT);
        var sio = io(srv);

        var clientSocket = client(srv, {
            reconnection: false
        });

        clientSocket.on('connect', function init() {
            expect(sio.nsps['/'].sockets.length).to.equal(1);

            // HERE
            sio.close();
            // HERE

        });

    });
```

My setup looks almost exactly like that. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

In the [examples](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-node-http-server) and in the test you have included, it shows a socket.io object being constructed with a server object that has been initialized in a different manner.

**Try this:**

```
var http = require('http').Server,
// ...
var httpServer = http().listen(port);
```

**Full example taken from [link](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-node-http-server) at time of posting:**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```